# PHP: Variable value is not showing

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

I am putting a html inside the php echo like .

```
echo '<td onclick="getdesc($descriptn)">';
```

My problem is onclick is not working i also tried like

```
echo '<td onclick="getdesc(\'$descriptn\')">';
```

But in this i am not geting the value of variable $descriptn is directly printing .

Please tell me what is the right way to do this ,

Comment: What about `?><td onclick="getdesc(<?= $descriptn ?>)"><?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
echo '<td   style="margin-top: 3px; padding: 3px 2px; background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #E9E9E9;" onclick="getdesc(\''.$descriptn.'\')" >';
```

Answer (score 3):

use double quote for this, that was the mistake.

```
echo "<td   style='margin-top: 3px; padding: 3px 2px; background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #E9E9E9;' onclick='getdesc(\'$descriptn\')' >";
```

Comment: I also tried but this will not work if the descriptn value will be a string

Answer (score 1):

[Single quotes vs double quotes](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm)

```
echo '<td   style="margin-top: 3px; padding: 3px 2px; background: none repeat scroll 0px 0px #E9E9E9;" onclick="getdesc(\''.$descriptn.'\')" >';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<td onclick="getdesc('.$descriptn.')">';
```

You may add it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach without concatenating strings:

```
$description = "hello world";
echo "<td onclick=\"getdesc('$description')\">";
```